# Is it possible to check via VBA if file exist on a sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint, vba, excel, hyperlink

I'm trying to write an Excel (2010) macro that at some point would have to confirm existence of a certain file (doc/pdf) on a corporate sharepoint site.
The file is accessible through Internet Explorer (all rights are granted to the user).
I have a direct link to that file.
I don't need to open it, just check if it's there.

If this was a local file, I'd use Dir() to check if the file exists.
However, this won't work with URIs.

I tried a method based on GET via objHttp but the only response I recieve is a wepage stating that "I am not authorized to view this page" [in  tag].

Is this doable in any way?

Comment: Is the link you have accessible directly? i.e. with no logon/saved logon in the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
Function checkFile(URLStr As String) As Boolean
    Dim oHttpRequest As Object
    Set oHttpRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    With oHttpRequest
        .Open "GET", URLStr, False, [Username], [Password]
        .setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
        .setRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
    End With
    If oHttpRequest.Status = 200 Then
        checkFile = True
    Else
        checkFile = False
    End If
End Function
```

`URLStr` should be something like "http://sharepoint/site/user.xlsx".  Enter your Username/Password in the `.Open` line to pass them to the site, and this should work for any URI (I was testing it against .xlsx files for example).  I should point out that on my internal SharePoint sites, I don't need to pass the UN/PW in order to run this function, so if that ends up being the case for you, just remove those parameters from the `.Open` call.  Also, all the header stuff probably isn't necessary, but I always have them in my requests so I left them in.

Answer (score -1):

I Dont know may this help you or not? But I am sharing my thoughts to you. 
You can use http web request for that. as given below example:

```
public void CheckWebFileExist()

{

try

{

    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;



    // Create a request for the URL.         

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("myAddress");



    // If required by the server, set the credentials.

    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;



    // Get the response.

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();



    //check response status

    if (string.Compare(response.StatusDescription, "OK", true) == 0)

    {

        //URL exists so that means file exists

    }

    else

    {

        //URL does not exist so that means file does not exist

    }      
}
catch (Exception error)

{

    //error catching

}
}
```

Let me know if this help you or not?

Comment: that's C# code , you can have idea about the logic or convert it.

Comment: I tried that. It looked promising because WebClient() is available in C++/C# and VB (in .NET). But apparently it's not recognized in VB for Applications. Thanks anyway for your contribution.