# Access Denied when checking file exists on sharepoint from vba

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to check if a file exists in SharePoint 2010 from Excel 2010 VBA. I took this code from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493756/is-it-possible-to-check-via-vba-if-file-exist-on-a-sharepoint-site).

```
Function checkFile(URLStr As String) As Boolean
Dim oHttpRequest As Object
Set oHttpRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
With oHttpRequest
    .Open "GET", URLStr, False
    .setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
    .setRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
    .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    .send
End With
If oHttpRequest.Status = 200 Then
    checkFile = True
Else
    checkFile = False
End If
End Function
```

When I do so, vba is throwing an error: 'Access Denied Error for this object'

It fails on the line `.send`

I figured out that the error code is **-2147024891**.

I checked the Sharepoint permissions and they should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My URL with http, but access to sharepoint is granted with https only (at lest at a certain version). Changing the URL solved the access issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function checkFile( URLStr As String) As Boolean
Dim oHttpRequest As Object
Dim GetResult As  Integer
Set oHttpRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
With oHttpRequest
    .Open "GET", URLStr, False
    .setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
    .setRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
    .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

End With
On Error GoTo HttpError
    oHttpRequest.send '!!!!!!here code stops!!!!!!!
HttpError:
     GetResult    = 00

GetResult = oHttpRequest.Status
If  GetResult  = 200 Then
    checkFile = True
Else
    checkFile = False
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the authentication user info.

```
oHttp.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + _
        Base64Encode(authUser + ":" + authPass)
```

Here is some info

http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/snippets/basicauth

[How to pass authentication credentials in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149169/how-to-pass-authentication-credentials-in-vba)

Comment: I am singed in to my shareroom, so this should not cause the issue I guess