# excel - 'Exit For' loop not working in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder on sharepoint/onedrive business that contains Excel files. These files are produced daily by system and named by that date.
[image]

> 22.05.2021.xlsx

> 21.05.2021.xlsx

> 20.05.2021.xlsx

I am trying VBA script that can detect what is latest date that the system creates in this folder.

```
Sub Latest_file_in_range()

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For x = Now() To (Now() - 15) Step -1

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="https://***-my.sharepoint.com/***/" & Format(x, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsx", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever
     If Err = 0 Then
         MsgBox x
         Exit For
     End If
Next

End Sub
```

Basically, I try to run a for loop backward from today and to exit at any loop that file is detected. This does not work. The script opens all files in the folder without stopping at the first file.

i.e. my expected result is that MsgBox shows latest file:

> 22.05.2021.xlsx

Please help me with this, great thanks.

Comment: `I am trying VBA script that can detect what is latest date that the system creates in this folder.` Er, why not loop through the files and check the created date? You want the latest file right?>

Comment: If the first date you try doesn't work, Err will not be 0 thereafter, so you won't see a message or exit the loop. Assign the result of `workbooks.open` to a variable and test if that is `Nothing`.

Comment: Hi @SiddharthRout, created date may not work. Created date just depends on  when the system runs. File name is the most reliable.

Comment: Created date will give you the latest file created. once you identify that, you can retrieve the name of that file. What I mean is, say there are five files. Your code will get the created date using `FileDateTime()` of each file. Once it identifies which file is the latest created file, all you need is to get the name of the file. I of course understand that the file created date may not be the same at the file name.

Comment: **Note:** My above logic will be of no use if the system names the file randomly. For example it created and named the file `24/5/2021` yesterday and today it creates and names a file `23/5/2021` (an oder date). Then of course you will not get `24/5/2021`

Comment: hi @SiddharthRout, this cannot cover case of the system has adjustment and creates file for old value date. e.g. on 25 May it creates file for value date 20.05.2021.xlsx while file 22.05.2021.xlsx is created earlier.

Comment: Yup that is what I mentioned above

Comment: You can also directly check if the file `"https://***-my.sharepoint.com/***/" & Format(x, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsx"` exists in sharepoint without opening it in Excel. Here is one [example (Untested)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493756/is-it-possible-to-check-via-vba-if-file-exist-on-a-sharepoint-site) There are many more links if you search google

Comment: If you still want to continue with your approach then follow what @Rory mentioned above.

Comment: So.. What is the definition of the latest file? Is it the latest saved file?

Comment: You could use PowerQuery - **Data > Get Data > From File > From Folder** will create a list of all files in the folder.  Then use **Transform > Extract > Text Before Delimiter** to remove the file extension.  Convert the file name to a real date and return the latest date.

Comment: Having said that in last comment - will probably need a few changes to look at a Sharepoint folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rory wrote in the comments, your problem is that if the first file cannot be found (that's the one with the date of *today*), the err-object is set to an error (1004). Once the error is set, it stays there unless another error occurs that set it to the new error number. Opening a file successfully does *not* set the err to 0.

Two ways to handle that. A) Reset the error manually using `Clear`.

```
For x = Now() To (Now() - 15) Step -1
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="https://***-my.sharepoint.com/***/" & Format(x, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsx", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever
    If Err = 0 Then
        MsgBox x
        Exit For
    End If
    Err.Clear
Next
```

B) Write the result of the open-Command into a variable and check if it is set:

```
For x = Now() To (Now() - 15) Step -1
    Dim wb as Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("https://***-my.sharepoint.com/***/" & Format(x, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsx", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever)
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox x
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Great thank FunThomas and @Rory, your suggestions work like a charm. They are simple and easy to understand to address what I missed.